# How to store contact details as a class variables android

Tags: android, class, android-contacts

This could be a JAVA question, but I didn't know how to frame it. So, moderators please change the tags if needed.

I am retrieving Contact's information, using the below code...

```
Cursor cur = cr_RC.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
        null, null, null);

if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String id = cur.getString(cur
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String name = cur
                .getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        if (Integer
                .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
            Cursor pCur = cr_RC.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                            + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                // Do something with phones
            }
            pCur.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create a class, which holds all these values(multiple contacts) and later retrieve them to store them in database. But, I am not quite sure how to write that class. Can some one help me with this?  How do I store these multiple contacts in a class? How do i differentiate one contact with another, while storing or retrieving a contact's information?

List of the things i want to store..

1. Name
2. All phone numbers
3. Email IDs - not included in code here.
4. Contact's Photo - not included in code here.

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Where r u getting Email Id and photo?

Comment: @TarunDroid, I have not included that part in the code above, as my question was not to get the values, but to store them as class members and retrieve them later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a **Object-Oriented-Programming** question.

I suppose you want to have multiple "Contacts" so you are probably talking about **member variables, not (static) class variables.**

You need to create a class that has all the memer variables you need for storing the data. Then write getter and setter methods to add new data to the object or get data from the object.

The class you want could for example look like this:

**MyContact.java**

```
public  class MyContact {

    private String name; 
    private ArrayList<String> phoneNumbers;  // a list for storing multiple numbers
    private ArrayList<String> emailIDs;

    // storing bitmaps permanently is probably not the best solution
    private Bitmap photo; // BE VERY CAREFUL HERE, Bitmaps use lots of memory so only keep them in memory as long as needed

    public MyContact() {
        phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
        emailIDs = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addPhoneNumer(String number) {
         this.phoneNumbers.add(number);
    }

    public void addEmailID(String number) {
         this.emailIDs.add(number);
    }

    public String getName() {
          return name;
    }

    public String getEmaiIDByIndex(int index) {
          return emailIDs.get(index);
    }

    // and so on...
}
```

And then, if you want to save values in your Class:

```
MyContact c = new MyContact();

c.setName("somename");
c.addPhoneNumber("145325235235");
c.addPhoneNumber("94205325");
c.addEmailID("emailid");

// to get information and store it somewhere else:
YourDatabase.storeValue(c.getName());  // just as an example
```

Comment: Okie.. this sounds good.. Now, How do I retrieve this information? Let's say once I store all the values as class members, i want to retrieve all of them, to store in database. How do I go about it?

Comment: If you want to retreive information, siply use the getter-methods of your class as in the example code above.

Comment: Okie.. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

**This is the complete solution I am using**

*This method will return ArrayList>, each hash map contains complete information of one contact that you want.*

**output**

```
[
{phone=992-561-1618;848-807-4440;, 
contactId=1, 
photo=android.graphics.Bitmap@44f40aa0, 
address=Zalavadia Strret
Manavadar, Gujarat 362630
India, 
email=birajzalavadia@gmail.com;biraj@tasolglobal.com;, 
name=Biraj Zalavadia
}
]

public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> getContacts() {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> contacts = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        final String[] projection = new String[] { RawContacts.CONTACT_ID, RawContacts.DELETED };

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        final Cursor rawContacts = mSmartAndroidActivity.managedQuery(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);

        final int contactIdColumnIndex = rawContacts.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.CONTACT_ID);
        final int deletedColumnIndex = rawContacts.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.DELETED);

        if (rawContacts.moveToFirst()) {
            while (!rawContacts.isAfterLast()) {
                final int contactId = rawContacts.getInt(contactIdColumnIndex);
                final boolean deleted = (rawContacts.getInt(deletedColumnIndex) == 1);

                if (!deleted) {
                    HashMap<String, Object> contactInfo = new HashMap<String, Object>() {
                        {
                            put("contactId", "");
                            put("name", "");
                            put("email", "");
                            put("address", "");
                            put("photo", "");
                            put("phone", "");
                        }
                    };
                    contactInfo.put("contactId", "" + contactId);
                    contactInfo.put("name", getName(contactId));
                    contactInfo.put("email", getEmail(contactId));
                    contactInfo.put("photo", getPhoto(contactId) != null ? getPhoto(contactId) : "");
                    contactInfo.put("address", getAddress(contactId));
                    contactInfo.put("phone", getPhoneNumber(contactId));
                    contactInfo.put("isChecked", "false");
                    contacts.add(contactInfo);
                }
                rawContacts.moveToNext();
            }
        }

        rawContacts.close();

        return contacts;
    }
```

**Additional Methods which are used by** `getContacts()` **method.**

```
private static String getName(int contactId) {
        String name = "";
        final String[] projection = new String[] { Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };

        final Cursor contact = mSmartAndroidActivity.managedQuery(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, Contacts._ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(contactId) }, null);

        if (contact.moveToFirst()) {
            name = contact.getString(contact.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            contact.close();
        }
        contact.close();
        return name;

    }

    /**
     * This method used to get mail id from contact id.
     * 
     * @param contactId
     *            represented contact id
     * @return represented {@link String}
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static String getEmail(int contactId) {
        String emailStr = "";
        final String[] projection = new String[] { Email.DATA, // use
                // Email.ADDRESS
                // for API-Level
                // 11+
                Email.TYPE };

        final Cursor email = mSmartAndroidActivity.managedQuery(Email.CONTENT_URI, projection, Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(contactId) }, null);

        if (email.moveToFirst()) {
            final int contactEmailColumnIndex = email.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA);

            while (!email.isAfterLast()) {
                emailStr = emailStr + email.getString(contactEmailColumnIndex) + ";";
                email.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        email.close();
        return emailStr;

    }

    /**
     * This method used to get {@link Bitmap} From contact id.
     * 
     * @param contactId
     *            represented contact id
     * @return represented {@link Bitmap}
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static Bitmap getPhoto(int contactId) {
        Bitmap photo = null;
        final String[] projection = new String[] { Contacts.PHOTO_ID };

        final Cursor contact = mSmartAndroidActivity.managedQuery(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, Contacts._ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(contactId) }, null);

        if (contact.moveToFirst()) {
            final String photoId = contact.getString(contact.getColumnIndex(Contacts.PHOTO_ID));
            if (photoId != null) {
                photo = getBitmap(photoId);
            } else {
                photo = null;
            }
        }
        contact.close();

        return photo;
    }

    /**
     * This method used to get {@link Bitmap} From photo id.
     * 
     * @param photoId
     *            represented photo id
     * @return represented {@link Bitmap}
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static Bitmap getBitmap(String photoId) {
        final Cursor photo = mSmartAndroidActivity.managedQuery(Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { Photo.PHOTO }, Data._ID + "=?", new String[] { photoId }, null);

        final Bitmap photoBitmap;
        if (photo.moveToFirst()) {
            byte[] photoBlob = photo.getBlob(photo.getColumnIndex(Photo.PHOTO));
            photoBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photoBlob, 0, photoBlob.length);
        } else {
            photoBitmap = null;
        }
        photo.close();
        return photoBitmap;
    }

    /**
     * This method used to get address from contact id.
     * 
     * @param contactId
     *            represented contact id
     * @return represented {@link String}
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static String getAddress(int contactId) {
        String postalData = "";
        String addrWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
        String[] addrWhereParams = new String[] { String.valueOf(contactId), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };

        Cursor addrCur = mSmartAndroidActivity.managedQuery(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, addrWhere, addrWhereParams, null);

        if (addrCur.moveToFirst()) {
            postalData = addrCur.getString(addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS));
        }
        addrCur.close();
        return postalData;
    }

    /**
     * This method used to get phone number from contact id.
     * 
     * @param contactId
     *            represented contact id
     * @return represented {@link String}
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static String getPhoneNumber(int contactId) {

        String phoneNumber = "";
        final String[] projection = new String[] { Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE, };
        final Cursor phone = mSmartAndroidActivity.managedQuery(Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(contactId) }, null);

        if (phone.moveToFirst()) {
            final int contactNumberColumnIndex = phone.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);

            while (!phone.isAfterLast()) {
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber + phone.getString(contactNumberColumnIndex) + ";";
                phone.moveToNext();
            }

        }
        phone.close();
        return phoneNumber;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as i mentioned, I want to store them as a class members, so looking for that kind of answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create pojo contact class. Example for name and numbers:

```
public class Contact {
  private String name;
  private List<String> numbers;


  getName(){
    return name;
  }

  setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  getNumbers(){
    return numbers;
  }

  setNumbers(List<String> numbers) {
    this.numbers= numbers;
  }
}
```